# Multiple color picker in wordpress metabox not saving

Tags: php, wordpress

I am following this article: http://javatechig.com/wordpress/how-to-implement-color-picker-with-wordpress on how to put color picker in my metabox, and it's showing allright, but when I try to save it, nothing is saved. Weird thing is that I tried this on one site, and basically copy pasted this entire procedure, and it worked. This time I need 2 color inputs. So I created my metabox and save form:

```
<?php 

if ( ! function_exists( 'Theme_add_meta_box' ) ){
    function Theme_add_meta_box(){
        add_meta_box( 'breadcrumbs-image-page-metabox-options', esc_html__('Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme' ), 'Theme_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box', 'page', 'side', 'low');
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'Theme_add_meta_box' );

if ( ! function_exists( 'Theme_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box' ) ){
    function Theme_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box( $post ){
        $custom = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
        $breadcrumbs_image = (isset($custom["breadcrumbs_image"][0])) ? $custom["breadcrumbs_image"][0] : '';
        $headline_color = (isset($custom["headline_color"][0])) ? $custom["headline_color"][0] : '';
        $breadcrumbs_color = (isset($custom["breadcrumbs_color"][0])) ? $custom["breadcrumbs_color"][0] : '';

        ?>
        <style type="text/css">
            .hidden{display: none;}
            .postbox .separator{padding-top: 20px;margin-top: 20px;border-top: 1px solid #ddd;}
        </style>
        <p>
            <input id="Theme_breadcrumbs_image_input" type="hidden" name="breadcrumbs_image" value="<?php echo $breadcrumbs_image; ?>"/>
            <a title="<?php esc_html_e('Add Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme'); ?>" href="#" id="add-post-breadcrumbs_image">
            <?php
                if(isset($custom["breadcrumbs_image"][0]) ){
                    echo '<img width="254" src="'.$breadcrumbs_image.'" />';
                } else{
                    esc_html_e('Add Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme');
                } ?></a>
            <?php
                if (!isset($custom["breadcrumbs_image"][0])) {
                    echo '<a title="'.esc_html__('Remove Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme').'" href="#" id="remove-post-breadcrumbs_image" class="hidden">'.esc_html__('Remove Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme').'</a>';
                } else{
                    echo '<a title="'.esc_html__('Remove Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme').'" href="#" id="remove-post-breadcrumbs_image" >'.esc_html__('Remove Breadcrumbs Image', 'Theme').'</a>';
                }
            ?>
        </p>
        <p class="separator">
        <h4><?php esc_attr_e('Headline Color', 'Theme' ); ?></h4>
            <input class="color-field" type="text" name="headline_color" value="<?php echo '#'.$headline_color; ?>"/>
        <h4><?php esc_attr_e('Breadcrumbs Color', 'Theme' ); ?></h4>
            <input class="color-field" type="text" name="breadcrumbs_color" value="<?php echo '#'.$breadcrumbs_color; ?>"/>
        </p>
        <?php
    }
}

if ( ! function_exists( 'Theme_save_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box' ) ){
    function Theme_save_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box( $post ){
        if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
            return;
        }
        $breadcrumbs_image = (isset($_POST["breadcrumbs_image"])) ? $_POST["breadcrumbs_image"] : '';
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "breadcrumbs_image", $breadcrumbs_image);

        $headline_color = (isset($_POST["headline_color"])) ? $_POST["headline_color"] : '';
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "headline_color", $headline_color);

        $breadcrumbs_color = (isset($_POST["breadcrumbs_color"])) ? $_POST["breadcrumbs_color"] : '';
        update_post_meta($post->ID, "breadcrumbs_color", $breadcrumbs_color);

    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'Theme_save_breadcrumbs_image_meta_box' );
```

I have image upload in as well, and it's working as it should.

I initialized my colorpicker in javascript

```
 $('.color-field').each(function(){
     $(this).wpColorPicker();
 });
```

I actually added `.each` to see if the initialization needs to be separate per input field but there was no difference even when I put this

```
 $('.color-field').wpColorPicker();
```

I also enqueued colorpicker

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-color-picker');
wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-color-picker');
```

in my functions.php where my admin scripts are enqueued.

I can choose color, I see the color pickers, and when I go to save them, nothing happens :\ I get empty color pickers when the page refreshes. Image upload works fine (I didn't include the js code for it here, but it works, and saves).

So what am I missing?

Comment: Open your Console and see if there are any Javascript Errors when you click save. Also without an example to look at it's difficult to pinpoint the issue.

Any live samples?

Comment: There are no js errors, and this is a theme in development, so it's not live...

Answer (score -1):

I would STRONGLY recommend you take a look at the Piklist plugin for WP.

Specifically [here](https://piklist.com/user-guide/docs/fields/colorpicker/)...

Piklist is an awesome framework for WP development and could not be simpler or more powerful.

Comment: Sorry but I'm avoiding any 3rd party plugin involvement. This is a simple meta-box adding to the wordpress page.